# How can I replace all special characters in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, special-characters

I want to replace all special characters in my multidimensional array:

```
array(1) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["two"]=>
    array(1) {
      [three]=>
      array(1) {
        ["four"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["five"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["Ele╠phant"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["My_Ele╠phant_walks.eps"]=>
              array(3) {
                ["six"]=>
                string(106) "one/two/three/four/five/Ele╠phant/My_Ele╠phant_walks.eps"
                ["seven"]=>
                string(6) "seven"
                ["eight"]=>
                string(19) "eight"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So as a result it should look like this:

```
array(1) {
      ["one"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["two"]=>
        array(1) {
          [three]=>
          array(1) {
            ["four"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["five"]=>
              array(1) {
                ["Ele?phant"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["My_Ele?phant_walks.eps"]=>
                  array(3) {
                    ["six"]=>
                    string(106) "one/two/three/four/five/Ele?phant/My_Ele?phant_walks.eps"
                    ["seven"]=>
                    string(6) "seven"
                    ["eight"]=>
                    string(19) "eight"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

For strings there is a very nice tool, that does exactly what I need:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

And I am looking for the same thing for arrays

Comment: Use `array_walk_recursive` with it

Comment: if [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is too much for you, you can try an `array_search` within a `do while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function a_iconv(array &$arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      a_iconv($arr[$key]);
    } else {
      unset($arr[$key]);
      $arr[iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $key)] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $val);
    }
  }
}
```

That function should do it.

```
function a_iconv(array $src) {
  $dst = array();
  foreach ($src as $key => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) {
      $dst[iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $key)] = a_iconv($val);
    } else {
      $dst[iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $key)] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $val);
    }
  }
  return $dst;
}
```

That one should do it without modifying the original array, returning the new version instead.
Both functions recursively apply themselves on any array in your original array, applying iconv on any non array entry. I didn't checked for objects since I assume you don't have some in your array. Use `get_object_vars()` if that happens to be the case.

Comment: I tested `a_iconv($myarray)` but there are still the symbols im my array (Ele╠phant)

Comment: I tested both functions but unfortunatelly there are still the symbols in my array

Comment: There was a little mistake in the first function that is now corrected. However, the second function works fine.

Comment: Thank you! Now the first function works!! but only with `one/two/three/four/five/Ele?phant/My_Ele?phant_walks.eps`. `array(1) { ["Ele╠phant"]=>array(1) {  ["My_Ele╠phant_walks.eps"]=>` are still with special characters

Comment: At least you can use the first function, but that's quite odd.

Comment: Are you aware that the second function doesn't modify the array you send as an argument and that you have to catch the returned array since it's a new one ? `$arr2 = a_iconv($arr);` That way.

Comment: Hmm, I am still confused. Did you expect that `array(1) { ["Ele╠phant"]=>array(1) { ["My_Ele╠phant_walks.eps"]=>` would also be transformed into `array(1) { ["Ele?phant"]=>array(1) { ["My_Ele?phant_walks.eps"]=>` in your first function?

Comment: ah ok,I will check out what you said, maybe this is the issue

Comment: No, If I write `$arr2 = a_iconv($arr);`  then it is even worse. The result is `NULL`

Comment: That means that the reason why the second function didn't work was that you didn't used the returned value. That's a progress. Did you, by any chance, copy both functions in the same file ? NULL is the result you'll get if the second function uses the first one when it calls a_iconv, for example like if you copy both functions but rename the second whithout renaming it when it's recusrsively called.

Comment: No I didn't copied the function twice. Right now I am using only the first function

Comment: Is it solving your issue ?

Comment: If I use the second function like this `$newarray = a_iconv($myarray);` and `var_dump($newarray);` then it is JUST changing  `string(106) "one/two/three/four/five/Ele?phant/My_Ele?phant_walks.eps"` BUT NOT `array(1) {
            ["Ele╠phant"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["My_Ele╠phant_walks.eps"]=>`

Comment: Do you know what I mean is the problem?

Comment: Same with the first function

Comment: (Yes the problem why the second function didn't work at first was the return value, that is correct)

Comment: No, wait, I post the issue in my question, maybe then it will be clear I guess

Comment: Ah, I saw, you made a change! Tested it and working!!

Comment: Yes, this was all the time my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the array to a json string, convert the special characters in this string, and convert the json string back to an array.

```
$json = json_encode($array);
$json = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $json);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, I just made a test. But if I then `var_dump($array);` there are still the symbols Ele╠phant

Comment: Are you sure the `iconv` function you provided removes these characters?

Comment: When I use it with a normal string yes

Comment: It's slow and it will fail during encode if the file contains invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
function custonDecode($src) {
   $dst = array();
   foreach ($src as $key => $val) {
     if (is_array($val)) {
       $dst[iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $key)] = a_iconv($val);
     } else {
       $dst[$key] = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $val);
     }
  }
  return $dst;
}

 print_r(custonDecode($yourArray));
```

Comment: Tested it, but I get no result